# critical numbers of a complex function $ f(x) = 2 x - 5 x^{\frac{2}{5}} $

Tags: calculus, functions

Critical numbers of $ f(x) = 2 x - 5 x^{2/5} $ are 1,$0$

How come $0$ is also a critical number?

I found the critical number 1 this way:

$f'(x) = 2 - 5 \ \frac {2}{5}  \ x^{-\frac{3}{5}}$

$ x^{\frac{3}{5}} = 1$

Comment: What is generally the domain of fifth root of $x$? Is it really only the positives?

Comment: Well, negatives would also be included, but wouldn't x^2 cancel out them anyway? So effectively, you'll only have positive values, whatever x value you plug in into the function.

Comment: But...are you allowed to put in negatives values for x?

Comment: Yeah, why not? It's basically fifth root of x^2, isn't it? nvm, I answered my own question, I guess. I confused domain with range (y)

Comment: So...if you are allowed to put in negatives numbers, what does that mean for the domain of the function?

Comment: In essence, my above post should also address your second question about that other critical number. You may want to gtaph the function with a graphing calculator

Comment: Well, I plotted it in wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2x%E2%88%925x^2%2F5 and... I don't see anything peculiar at x = 0 that could tell me that the graph has a critical point there.

Comment: How do you go about computing $0^{-3/5}$? $0^{-3/5} = \frac{1}{0^{3/5}} = \frac{1}{0}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Critical values of a function occur where the derivative is zero or where the derivative is undefined.

Since $f'(x)=2 - 2x^{\frac{-3}{5}} = 2 - \frac{2}{x^{\frac{3}{5}}} = 2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt[5]{x^3}}$

Hence, $f'(0)$ is undefined since we are dividing by zero.

Also, $f'(1) =0,$ therefore the critical values are 0 and 1.

Comment: A great lesson learned here: get rid of negative exponents, they may hide a big problem... You should also change the fractional exponent to a 5th root. In this case, it doesn't matter much, but if the denominator had been an even number, the domain of the derivative would have changed a lot...

Comment: @BernardMassé I would normally have written has the fifth root of x cubed, but was too lazy to look up the latex code.  I dislike the way the fractional exponent looks in the denominator, so I changed it.  Thanks for the good advice!